# Transact SQL decrement table value then return item for MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In 1 server request sql, how to check if the value of the table is greater than zero, if the value is greater than zero then decrement the value then return the row of that table..

```
counthere = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName1 > 0 AND ColumnName2 = 'xx';
if (counthere > 0)
{
    valuehere = SELECT ColumnName1 FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName2 = 'xx';
    UPDATE TableName SET ColumnName1 = (valuehere - 1) WHERE ColumnName2 = 'xx';
    SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName2 = 'xx';
}
```

i want to use Transact-SQL to perform 1 request to the server.. is this possible? can you help me for an example? thanks folks..

---

i used @Arion's Solution but still i got this error..

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS(SELECT * 
           FROM inventorylist 
           WHERE BarcodeNum' at line 1
[Err] IF EXISTS(SELECT * 
           FROM inventorylist 
           WHERE BarcodeNumber = '9555440808279' AND NotificationQuantity > 0)
THEN
      UPDATE inventorylist 
      SET NotificationQuantity = NotificationQuantity - 1
      WHERE BarcodeNumber = '9555440808279'

      SELECT *
      FROM inventorylist
      WHERE BarcodeNumber = '9555440808279'
END
[Msg] Finished - Unsuccessfully
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. i just want to use transact-sql.. :)

Comment: T-SQL in MySQL? I've never heard of that.

Comment: ahhhh.. so there's no T_SQL in MYSQL...

Comment: Transact SQL is the dialect of SQL used by MS SQL Server and Sybase server. I'm not sure if there's a specific name for the dialect of SQL used by MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you right. You want something like this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName1 > 0 AND ColumnName2 = 'xx') 
    THEN 
        UPDATE TableName SET ColumnName1 = ColumnName1-1 WHERE ColumnName2 = 'xx'
        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            TableName
        WHERE 
            ColumnName2 = 'xx'

END IF
```

Hope this helps

Comment: hello.. i got this error on execution.. 

     You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF(EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM inventorylist WHERE BarcodeNumber = '9555440808279' A' at line 1